# How to prevent random WiFi connection drops in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I am running 20.04 on a [ThinkPad P72](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/think-workstations/oil-gas-and-energy-industry/ThinkPad-P72/p/22WS2WPWP72). After updating to 20.04, the WiFi drops out anywhere from a few times a day to a dozen times an hour, and is cranky about reconnecting (it will sometimes reconnect if I turn WiFi off and back on), unless I reboot. My WiFi point is not presenting connectivity issues for other operating systems.

I have heard from a friend who recently upgraded to 20.04 that they have been seeing random connectivity drops over WiFi also.

**Note:** I do not know what kind of debug or log files or diagnostics would be useful here, but if you request specifics in the comments I will do my best to provide them.

---

**Edit:** These disconnect events do not show up at all in `/var/log/syslog`.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:0030]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

With 2.4Ghz set to Channel 'Auto'

```
% iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:382   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

After switching to Channel 36 on the 5GHz band:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

After switching to Channel 48 on the 5GHz band:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:13   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

After switching to Channel 149 on the 5 GHz band:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

After switching to Channel 161 on the 5GHz band:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

After switching to Channel 1 on the 2.4 GHz band:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

After switching to Channel 6 on the 2.4 GHz band:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:8   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

After switching to Channel 11 on the 2.4 GHz band:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"R910a-2DB972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: F4:63:49:2D:B9:72   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5282d5c87b2f  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

```
$ iwlist wlp0s20f3 freq
wlp0s20f3  32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
```

Comment: Note the exact times of a drop and reconnect, then check /var/log/syslog around those times.

Comment: @user535733 /var/log/syslog shows ***nothing*** (I have had a dozen drops today, and there are not even any events for today in the syslog).

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwconfig` and `iwlist wlxxx freq` both when connected to your wifi.

Comment: Giggle. You were supposed to sub your wireless interface name into the iwlist command. The correct command is `iwlist wlp0s20f3 freq`. Do you only have a 2.4 GHz wireless network available? What 2.4 GHz channel is set in your router?

Comment: @heynnema Pffff. *You* are clearly used to playing with people who have a full deck. ;) I can use my wireless router in 5Ghz band if need be. 2.4GHz hannel is set to 'Auto' on my router.

Comment: Channel 2 is an odd channel to use. Try channels 1 or 6 or 11 and see if things get better. You can also try channel 140 in the 5 GHz and see if it's more reliable. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema RogerWilco. (Oh! Wilco! I'm gonna put *Mermaid Avenu* on...)

Comment: Compare your `iwconfig` output with your earlier example.

Comment: You're setting the channel in the Franklin R910, correct? Try one of the other 1/6/11 channels. Report back.

Comment: For 5 GHz, use channel 140.

Comment: Channel 11 was the best on 2.4 GHz. Try channel 48 on 5 GHz. I'd prefer a higher channel, but your modem card only supports up to 140.

Comment: Is your Franklin R910 near any forms of interference  like, wireless telephone, microwave oven, etc? Who is your carrier, Sprint? Call them and have them check the hotspot, it may require a firmware update, or some tweaking on their part.

Comment: @heynnema Not from my house. Microwave across the house, and uncorrelated with WiFi drops. No CB, radio phone, no AM/FM radio. No TV. Just the laptops, bluetooth headset, and the router. (I checked with the network, and the tower is happy, healthy and robust also).

Comment: Switch off bluetooth. Retest. Then call Sprint.

Comment: @heynnema Have already called Sprint, did a network reset, did not change dropping behavior. Drops have happened with bluetooth off, *and* drops only started happening with 20.04 (a friend switching to 20.04 is in a similar boat): I used bluetooth headset plenty with 19.04 and 19.10 and had no WiFi drops. I have seen enough reports of WiFi going flakey upon upgrading to 20.04, that I am still pretty comfortable with that hypothesis.

Comment: So for now, other than picking channels to optimize the connection, then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema No way! *Super* helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a lot with my laptop, after about 1/2 a year I realised that ubuntu does not handle some wifi router signals well. WHat fixed it for me was disabaling IPv6, and selecting just one chanal on my router. (Before it was dinamic). I stoped having issues at home. Unfortunatly if im at school or a cafe then the issues show up again.

Comment: Thank you. However, this behavior seems to have emerged *only* after upgrading to 20.04 (from 19.10, previously 19.04, previously 18.10).